# Guidance required for copying filtered lines from one table to another

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have attached image that I hope helps...

I want to create the table of Barcodes and cost prices from the master table ..

I could get it to work copying just the barcodes but not the cost columns without a Supplier selection

When. I select a supplier it bombs out with Error 91..

The filters are et but is is filing on the Visrange.copy

[image: overview of issue]

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateBarcodeExportList()


      Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Create Barcode Export List'"
'=====================================================================================
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'=====================================================================================
    Dim FromWs As Worksheet
    Set FromWs = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File")
    
    Dim ToWs As Worksheet
    Set ToWs = Sheets("DATA - Barcode List")
    
    Dim FromTbl As ListObject
    Set FromTbl = FromWs.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
    
    Dim ToTbl As ListObject
    Set ToTbl = ToWs.ListObjects("BCODE_Table")
   
    
    Dim ToTbl_LastRow As Long
    Dim VisRange As Range
    Dim Torange As Range
    Dim VisRange2 As Range
    Dim Torange2 As Range
    Dim Maxlimit As Variant
    
    Dim Supplier As Variant
'=====================================================================================
        ' Clear
        
        With ToTbl
        
        'Check If any data exists in the table
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            'Clear Content from the table
            .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
        End If
        
    End With
    Range("a5").Activate
ToTbl.Resize Range("a4:c5")
'=====================================================================================
     'Ensure Filteris reset
     
       With FromTbl
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
     End With
     
     Maxlimit = ToWs.Range("b1").Value
     Supplier = ToWs.Range("b2").Value
     Maxlimit = Maxlimit + 1
     
     ' Filter table
     
     If Supplier = "" Then
   FromTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array("Valid"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Else
FromTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array("Valid"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
FromTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array(Supplier), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End If

    
    ' Copy filtered table
    On Error Resume Next
    Set VisRange = FromTbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
       
     If VisRange Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "No Valid Barcodes Selected.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
     GoTo ProcessEnd
    End If
    

Set VisRange = Application.Intersect(VisRange, FromWs.Range("F2: f" & Maxlimit))
Maxlimit = Maxlimit + 5

Set Torange = ToWs.Range("a5: a" & Maxlimit)

   
    
     VisRange.Copy
     Torange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   


    ToWs.Calculate
    With ToTbl.Range
        ToTbl_LastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
    End With
    
    
    ToTbl.Resize Range("a4:c" & ToTbl_LastRow)
ProcessEnd:
   
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

[image: Error after last correction]

Comment: `ToTbl.Resize Range("a4:c5")` should really be `ToTbl.Resize ToWs.Range("a4:c5")`  Always specify a worksheet when referring to a range, otherwise your code will not be robust.

Comment: Maybe your Intersect isn't returning a range? What's the role of `Maxlimit` in your process?

Comment: thanks Tim - Max limit allows me to chose how many records get created - I am using the barcode table as in import to other software which have varying numbers for the max you can in import in one go

Comment: Then maybe review taller's answer below, or at least check that your Intersect is working and returning a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below contains a bug. Let us assume that `Maxlimit` is set to 10, and if the data from row 2 to row 10 does NOT meet the filter criteria, `VisRange` will be `Nothing`. Attempting to execute `VisRange.Copy` under this condition will result in an error.

```
Set VisRange = Application.Intersect(VisRange, FromWs.Range("F2: f" & Maxlimit))
```

A filtered table might consist of non-continuous ranges. Coping first N rows does not work. The following code gathers the data into an array before updating the output table.

```vb
    ' Your code
    If VisRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Valid Barcodes Selected.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
        GoTo ProcessEnd
    End If
    
    '*** Revised code
    With FromWs
        ' it does NOT work on MAC (OP feedback)
        ' Set VisRange = Application.Intersect(VisRange, .Range("F2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)))
        Set VisRange = .Range("F:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    If Not VisRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim i As Integer, arrRes(), c As Range
        ReDim arrRes(1 To Maxlimit, 1 To 2)
        i = 1
        For Each c In VisRange.Cells
            If i > Maxlimit Then Exit For
            If c.Row > 1 Then
                arrRes(i, 1) = c.Value
                arrRes(i, 2) = c.Offset(0, 8).Value ' Column N
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
        ToWs.Range("a5").Resize(Maxlimit, 2).Value = arrRes
    Else
        MsgBox "No data in filtered table"
    End If
    ' ***
    ' your code
    ToWs.Calculate
```

Comment: thanks I will try this....will this just copy the one column? Sorry I haven't got to grips fully with array processing

Comment: I did this but get error on the Set Visrange statement - invalid procedure call or argument?  i limited the no of records to 10 and did not select a supplier so the filtered data was contiguos

Comment: There is a typo in my code. Try `With FromWs`. `Set VisRange = Application.Intersect(VisRange, FromWs.Range("F2: f" & Maxlimit))` is a range which has only ONE column. So revised code just uses the same logic.

Comment: sorry I still get error - I am trying to figure out before posting,,, I added a new image with error

Comment: Remove the last `s` from your code `c As Ranges`. btw, Column B can be filled in if you indicate the source of the data.

Comment: it still doesn't like the Set VisRange = Application.Intersect(VisRange, FromWs.Range("F2: f" & Maxlimit)) -  says invalid procedure call or argument... could it be MAC related.?

Comment: Column B would be populated from column N - Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure it is related with MAC. Let' get it done w/ `SpecialCells(...)`. Revised code populated column A and B.

Comment: thanks again - it is creating items ok now but there are a couple of issues - I am going to see if I can figure out before asking you!

Comment: Figured it out ... I had left old old that was doing the copy... This has been really helpful as I think i now understand more about Arrays than I did before this!  Really appreciate your help